# Error - Getting negative temperature while solving Quasi 1D flow in a Nozzle (JD Anderson Book)

Tags: fluid-dynamics

I am currently trying to solve Nozzle Flow problem from JD Anderson Book.

Here's my entire python code -

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

nx = 31
x = np.linspace(0,3,nx)

dx = x[2] - x[1]
gamma = 1.4
gamma_inverse = 1/gamma;
nt = 20
cfl = 0.5

#initial profile
rho = 1 - (0.3146*x)
T =   1 - (0.2314*x)
v = (0.1 + 1.09*x)*(T**0.5)
A = 1 + 2.2*((x-1.5)**2)
print(v)
print(T)
print(rho)

#stores predicted values
dv_dt_p = np.zeros((nx))
drho_dt_p = np.zeros((nx))
dT_dt_p = np.zeros((nx))

#stores corrected values
dv_dt_c = np.zeros((nx))
drho_dt_c = np.zeros((nx))
dT_dt_c = np.zeros((nx))

mass_flow_rate_initial = rho*v*A
throat = np.where(A==1)
throat = throat[0]
rho[throat]

rho_old = np.array((nx))
v_old = np.array((nx))
T_old = np.array((nx))

rho_old = rho[:]
v_old = v[:]
T_old = T[:]

for time in range(nt):

    rho_old = rho.copy()
    T_old = T.copy()
    v_old = v.copy()

    dt=np.min(0.5*dx/(T[1:]**0.5+v[1:]))
    
    #just checking for all the timesteps
    print(f"dt = {dt}")

    #Running the predictor loop
    for i in range(1,nx-1):
        dv_dx = (v[i+1] - v[i])/dx        
        dA_dx = (np.log(A[i+1]) - np.log(A[i]))/dx      
        drho_dx = (rho[i+1]-rho[i])/dx
        dT_dx = (T[i+1] - T[i])/dx

        t_rho = T[i]/rho[i]
    
        drho_dt_p[i] = -(rho[i]*dv_dx) -(rho[i]*v[i]*dA_dx) - (v[i]*drho_dx)
        dv_dt_p[i] = -(v[i]*dv_dx) - (gamma_inverse*(dT_dx + t_rho*drho_dx))
        dT_dt_p[i] = -(v[i]*dT_dx) - ((gamma - 1)*T[i]*(dv_dx + (v[i]*dA_dx)))
    
        #solution update    
        v[i] = v[i] + dv_dt_p[i]*dt
        rho[i] = rho[i] + drho_dt_p[i]*dt
        T[i] = T[i] + dT_dt_p[i]*dt 
    
    #Corrector step
    for i in range(1,nx-1):
        dv_dx = (v[i] - v[i-1])/dx
        dA_dx = (np.log(A[i]) - np.log(A[i-1]))/dx      
        drho_dx = (rho[i]-rho[i-1])/dx
        dT_dx = (T[i] - T[i-1])/dx

        drho_dt_c[i] = -(rho[i]*dv_dx) - (rho[i]*v[i]*dA_dx) - (v[i]*drho_dx)
        dv_dt_c[i] = -(v[i]*dv_dx) - (gamma_inverse*(dT_dx + t_rho*drho_dx))
        dT_dt_c[i] = -(v[i]*dT_dx) - (gamma - 1)*T[i]*(dv_dx + (v[i]*dA_dx)) 

    #solution update
        v[i] = v_old[i] + 0.5*(dv_dt_p[i] + dv_dt_c[i])*dt
        T[i] = T_old[i] + 0.5*(dT_dt_p[i] + dT_dt_p[i])*dt
        rho[i] = rho_old[i] + 0.5*(drho_dt_p[i] + drho_dt_c[i])*dt
    
    #inlet
    rho[0] = 1
    T[0] = 1
    v[0] = 2*v[1] - v[2]

    #outlet
    rho[nx - 1] = 2*rho[nx-2] - rho[nx-3]
    v[nx-1] = 2*v[nx-2] - v[nx-3]
    T[nx - 1] = 2*T[nx-2] - T[nx-3]
```

After about 20 iterations (`nt = 20`) I am getting a negative for temperature at `T[25]`

These are my temperature values

```
print(T)

[ 1.          1.03744881  0.96393473  0.96378318  0.93422584  0.91985233
  0.91127772  0.90790431  0.90632255  0.90396476  0.89865069  0.88840242
  0.87125983  0.84534127  0.81023042  0.76750794  0.71821834  0.6626661
  0.60477669  0.54447502  0.51316059  0.40819601  0.55829907  0.12201814
  0.81604993 -0.15955838  0.73151314  0.1736479   0.34083201  0.32972291
  0.31861381]
```

Is my code wrong somewhere?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: That's a lot of code for anyone here to understand, without an explanation what it's supposed to do. You might want to add a description of the equations you're trying to implement, along with the methods you use to solve these equations.

Comment: There is same code on https://github.com/erfanhamdi/Q1DNozzleVec . You can compare  it with your code to get what actually wrong in your code.